# Neo4j LIMIT if parameter is set

Tags: neo4j, cypher

is there a way to set a `LIMIT` only, if the parameter `{limit}` has an numeric value.

```
...
RETURN whatever
LIMIT {limit}
```

maybe in a way like this (i know, that the next code example does not work)

```
...
RETURN whatever
if({limit}>0)
  LIMIT {limit}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should process this logic in your application layer by building dynamic queries.

**Edit :**

This can simply be done like the example below (in php but possible in all languages)

```
public function doMatchQuery($limit = null)
{
    $query = 'MATCH (n) RETURN n';
    if ($limit && $limit !== 0) {
      // extend the query string
      $query .= ' LIMIT '.$limit;
    }
}

// Calling your function
$matchAll = $this->doMatchQuery(); // Return all n elements from the db
$matchFirstTen = $this->doMatchQuery(10); // Return the n elements with a limit of 10
```

Comment: I have done it like that, but i would be happy to find a solution in one query. thanks anyway.

Comment: I've edited with an example for your application layer